# Illegal characters found in parameter 'price' Python Binance

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, binance, binance-api-client

I'm not able to place the below order:

```
symbolTicker = 'SHIBUSDT'
orderPriceBuy = 0.00002650
orderPriceSell = 0.00002700
```

Code:

```
 buyOrder = client.create_order(
                    symbol=symbolTicker,
                    side=SIDE_BUY,
                    type=ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
                    timeInForce=TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
                    quantity=orderQuantityBuy,
                    price=orderPriceBuy)
```

Error:

```
raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1100): Illegal characters found in parameter 'price'; legal range is '^([0-9]{1,20})(\.[0-9]{1,20})?$'.
```

What seems to be wrong?

Comment: You need to pass the order prices as strings.

Comment: Can you please clarify? So orderPriceBuy = "0.00002650"
orderPriceSell = "0.00002700"?

Comment: Exactly just put this " character infront and behind them.

Comment: Do you have Discord? If you're ok with that.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Kalle#8406

Answer (score 1):

As the error stated the order prices need to be given as a string not as a number. It also showed you the RegEx of the legal range (which is quite nice). Note: You can't use numbers within RegEx and because the package does do RegEx checking it needs also a string.
Furthermore you can also check the docs of the package where it is surely documented.